# Create multidimensional array for duplicate key value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to read in array values from a csv and create sub-arrays which belong to the primary key field. E.g currently, say I have the following array structure & content...

```
$events['venue-id'] = 55
$events['event-date'] = 19/02/13;
$events['event-name'] = 'Sports Day';

$events['venue-id'] = 76
$events['event-date'] = 22/02/13;
$events['event-name'] = 'Gala Event';

$events['venue-id'] = 55
$events['event-date'] = 29/03/13;
$events['event-name'] = 'Some Other Event';
```

What would be the best way to use venue-id as a key in a parent array which the other data relating to it is assigned to sub arrays? A one to many relationship basically.

Comment: first of all: what did you already try? second: i'd advise to do it in an object oriented manner.

Comment: You just have to read each line of the CSV file, and foreach line, if the primary key exist in your final array, just add a sub array with data, in other case, create the entry, and add the sub array

Answer (score 0):

you can structure it like this if you want:

```
$events = array( 
  "55" => array(
    "event-date" => "19/02/03",
    "event-name" => "Sports Day"
   ),
  "76" => array(
   ...

);
```

this is assuming there won't be duplicate venue IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$res              = array();
if (($handle      = fopen("your_file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $res[$data[0]]['venue-id']         = $data[0];
        $res[$data[0]]['event-date']       = $data[1];
        $res[$data[0]]['event-name']       = $data[2];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```